# UITableViewCell is loading filler content instead of programmatic input?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains 3 `UILabels` and a `UIImageView`. I am setting this up via storyboards and have a `UITableView` class that is connected to the table cell. In that class I am wanting to handle the different UI objects and have the option to pass in information from my view controller.

Here is the .h of my table cell view class

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GBPathImageView *ProfileThumbnailImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profileDisplayNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profileUniversityNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profileNumberOfStringsLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *profileDisplayName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *profileThumbnailImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *profileUniversityName;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger profileNumberOfStrings;


- (id)initWithProfileImage:(UIImage *)profileImage
               displayName:(NSString *)displayName
            universityName:(NSString *)universityName
       numberOfUserStrings:(NSUInteger)numberOfStrings;
```

As you can see I have a property outlet that all of the storyboard objects are connected to. I also have properties for each piece of necessary information. In my view controllers

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method I am wanting to instantiate this custom cell with information that I pass in. I am wanting to set the information properties with the correct info and have it be setup in the view class.

Here is the code inside the previously mentioned method:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"UserProfileCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[StringrUserTableViewCell class]]) {

        StringrUserTableViewCell * userProfileCell = (StringrUserTableViewCell *)cell;

        userProfileCell.profileDisplayName = @"Alonso Holmes";

        //userProfileCell.profileDisplayNameLabel.text = @"User Name"; 
    }
```

I have two lines there, one is setting the information property for the name, and I have it in the view's .m file to set its text to that properties name. The problem that is happening is that the `profileDisplayName` property is null at the time it tries to set that `UILabels` text. How can I set this information at a time so that it will be there before the cell is loaded or when it's initially loading? You can also see a commented out line where I directly set the text of the `UILabel` right there. I would prefer not to do it this way because I want to leave the abstraction/logic to the view's class. The image view I setup is custom so it takes more code.

Comment: are you sure cell is not null?

Comment: The cell is definitely not null. I setup a test so that I can tap a cell and go to a new page. I pass information to that new page, which happens to be the information holding properties. The new page correctly displays the information. It seems that the UILabels and UIImageView are loading onto the screen before the information holding properties have taken the information. That is why the UI objects are loading blank. I need to somehow get the information to them prior to them loading on the screen.

Comment: if you set the cell correctly in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, they should be loaded together

Comment: can you try this:static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"UserProfileCell";

StringrUserTableViewCell *cell = (StringrUserTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


if(!cell){
 cell = [[StringUserTableViewCell alloc] init]; 
}

cell.profileDisplayName = @"Alonso Holmes";

Comment: I tried that and the cell does not return nil. It loads fine, but setting the UI objects load prior to the cell.profileDisplayName property information gets registered. That results in the text for that cell being blank and not populated with that info.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set your text in `profileDisplayName` which is `NSString` type not a `UILabel` class. ( see `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *profileDisplayName;` ).
Change your line of code:
here is the problem

userProfileCell.profileDisplayName = @"Alonso Holmes"; //Use Label Object instead of NSString

Comment: I am wanting to set the text of the UILabel by using the profileDisplayNameLabel.text property. I need to set the labels text to the NSString inside of the other property.

Comment: So will you you please share the line of code where you set the text in cell's Label

Comment: In the UiTableViewCell class I override the UILabels setter method.

- (void)setProfileDisplayNameLabel:(UILabel *)displayName
{
    [displayName setText:self.profileDisplayName];
}


I know it's confusing because the UILabel and NSString property names are so similar, but hopefully you can see here.

Comment: So when this setter method is going to be called? Because this is Label's setter method and you are not set the text of label. So I think it is not going to called right now.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you meant by that.?

Comment: I just want to know that from where you set text in profileDisplayNameLabel